# How to make a function that creates a generic list in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have 4 tables in the DB, each one has Id and Name, but they represent different things.
for each "thing" i have a different class, they all inherit from "thing". 
i have 4 functions :

```
List<thing1> getAllThings1();
List<thing2> getAllThings2();
List<thing3> getAllThings3();
List<thing4> getAllThings4();
```

each function reads from different table and creates the needed list.

Because i want to avoid code duplication i wanted to make a utility function that receives the table name (as string) and the type (thing1, thing2 ... etc), and returns `List<t>`.

unfortunately this is impossible (without reflection) :
[Create list of variable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493215/create-list-of-variable-type)

My current solution is that i have a function that returns a List, i call her in each "getAllThings#" and then manually convert each "thing" in the list to the proper thing by using ConvertAll and passing to him some converter.

I don't like this solution, it feels wrong because i create a list and create a new one. very inefficient. 
is there a better way to do it ?

thanks

Comment: Just out of interest why don't you want to use reflection?

Comment: Why can't you just infer the type from tablename and use a factory pattern to instance it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use generics?

```
public IList<T> GetAllThings<T>(string tableName) where T : Thing {
    return new List<T>();
}
```

You will be able to call it

```
IList<Thing4> things4 = thingProvider.GetAllThing<Thing4>( "thing4Table" );
```

you could also have a Dictionary for storing the table name for each type, so you don't have to provide the table name to the method.

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought about using template function

Answer (score 1):

try this quick and dirty. Not actual ,might contains error, you can use it as a reference.

Create a base class of thing having all common attributes

```
abstract ThingBase
{
   protected abstract   int Id {get;set;}
   protected abstract   string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Implement that base to your four things classes

```
public Thing1 :ThingBase
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
public Thing2 :ThingBase
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
public Thing3 :ThingBase
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
public Thing4 :ThingBase
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Create one more helper class, that will contain the list of all 4 things

```
public class YourThings
{
    public IList<Thing1> thing1 {get;set;}
    public IList<Thing2> thing2 {get;set;}
    public IList<Thing3> thing3 {get;set;}
    public IList<Thing4> thing4 {get;set;}

}
```

Now Write 4 different Select Queries in your SP and catch it as a dataset in your datalayer. Extract the   table and fill its respective list and return yourthing class to the UI layer.

```
public YourThings FunctionToReturnSingleYourThing()
{
}
```

of If You need a collection of YourThings , rebuild your logic and return like this

```
public List<YourThings> FunctionToReturnMultipleYourThings()
{
}
```