# How can I use list that created using reflection as normally create list

Tags: c#, list, generics, reflection

I created a list using method from this post
[Create list of variable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493215/create-list-of-variable-type)

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("ConsoleApplication4");
Type mytype = assembly.GetType("ConsoleApplication4.TestClass");
Type genericList = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(mytype);  
var mylist = Activator.CreateInstance(genericList);
```

my question is,after I create the list, how can I use the list in a function like following:

```
public void TestFunction<T>(List<T> mylist)
{
//do something here
}
```

Comment: Get a reference to the method (say by `myType.GetMethod("TestFunction")`) then leverage the [`MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) method to turn it into the proper generic call: `myMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(mytype)`. Then you can leverage the [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) method on it and pass in your `myList` object.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: I may be wrong, but I think the problem is that you can't pass it as an object of `List<*>` because you can't strongly cast it.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce: No, you wouldn't be able to turn it into a compile-time reference (unless you hard-coded that, which begs the question of why you're using reflection in the first place). That's why I have the `MakeGenericMethod` call there. It will create a version of `TestFunction<mytype>` (where `mytype` is that underlying `ConsoleApplication4.TestClass`). Then you can simply use the `Invoke` method on the resulting method info which you'll have passed in the `List<ConsoleApplication4.TestClass> mylist` already created in the sample code tcao has.

Comment: Overall, it's hard to say what the best course of action is here (reflection, dynamic, or refactoring) as tcao hasn't really provided us with much context as to _why or how_ he/she is doing what they're doing.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: I see, very cool technique.

Answer (score 1):

You'd lose static type analysis and compile-time checking (then again, given that you're working with reflection that's already happened), so you could just re-write your `TestFunction` as:

```
public void TestFunction(dynamic myList)
{
  // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could simply change the last line where you instantiate the list

```
dynamic mylist = Activator.CreateInstance(genericList);
```

That way the compiler won't try to infer the (runtime) type of myList but will defer this task to the DLR which in your case will be happy to tell you that it is some `List<mytype>`

If you at some point know the concrete type of `mylist` you can of course also use a simple cast

```
TestFunction((List<knownType>)mylist);
```

which one to prefer is mainly a matter of taste, there might be performance differences between the two but compared to the reflection based instantiation that difference is probably not going to be the bottleneck but if performance is of main concern use a profiler.

The reason why I suggest using dynamic at the instantiation site instead of in the method signature is to make most of the code statically typed so that the compiler can check most of the code. By using dynamic in the method signature you will make all calls of that method into dynamic calls whereas if you make the mylist dynamically typed you are only make the statements using mylist into dynamic calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the instance of mylist in the way you want, because the Compiler can not infer the closed type of List. You can only work with further reflection methods or inspect it with open generic types.