# Generic C# method which returns lists of the specified type

Tags: c#, generics

I currently have a static class that has 13 static fields, each of which is a static readonly list.  The objects in each list are of a different class, but all 13 classes extend the same class.

I am finding that there is repetition in the code.  Instead of having my code get each list 13 times over, I am toying with the idea of putting the lists into a dictionary, keyed on the type.  I can replace some operations with an iteration over the dictionary.

I prepared a simple working example but can't get a method to return lists of the specific type. **Can I make the GetList method return a List< T > ?**

```
public class ListGetter
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, List<Iab>> dict = new Dictionary<Type, List<Iab>>();

    public static List<Iab> GetList<T>() where T : Iab
    {
        List<Iab> list = dict[typeof(T)];
        return list;
    }
}

public interface Iab
{
}

public class ClassA : Iab
{
}

public class ClassB : Iab
{
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493215/create-list-of-variable-type

Comment: `List<T>` is invariant so you can't store them in your dictionary, although you can use `IEnumerable<Iab>` instead. Then you'll have to cast back down to a `List<T>` in the `GetList<T>` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You need to change the signature to return `List<T>` instead of `List<Iab>` and cast the contents to T.

```
public class ListGetter
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, List<Iab>> dict = new Dictionary<Type, List<Iab>>();

    static ListGetter()
    {
        var classAs = new List<Iab>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            classAs.Add(new ClassA());
        }
        dict.Add(typeof(ClassA), classAs);

        var classBs = new List<Iab>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            classBs.Add(new ClassB());
        }
        dict.Add(typeof(ClassB), classBs);

    }

    public static List<T> GetList<T>() where T : Iab
    {
        var list = dict[typeof(T)];
        return list.Cast<T>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could just using the IEnumerable extension method `OfType<T>` but it may be slower if you're frequently accessing the lists.

```
public class ListGetter2
{
    private static IList<Iab> _list;

    static ListGetter2()
    {
        _list = new List<Iab>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            _list.Add(new ClassA());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            _list.Add(new ClassB());
        }
    }

    public static IList<T> GetList<T>() where T : Iab
    {
        return _list.OfType<T>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand why we need return list.Cast<T>().ToList();
Why just return variable with concrete type List<Reader> doesn't work, if return type is List<T> and I call method with define concrete type, like in my example: var entities = dal.GetDataFromDataBase<Reader>()

Comment: @DmitrySokolov The ToList changes the result from `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>`. In the question, the author has a dictionary containing two classes that implement the same interface and is looking for a way to get the concrete types back as a list. That has to happen at runtime because that's when calling code specifies which type to return.