# How to convert a Type variable to a type to be used to create EF Core LINQ SQL queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to build a generic method to access all of my sql database table through my EF Core database context.

I am stuck on how to tell the context what table I want to access. Normally, of course, you can just use `context.Type.Where() etc.` where `Type` is the type of table you want to access.

Because I want the method to be generic, I don't know the type at compile time, only at run time, so I can't explicitly specify the `DbSet` type I want.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public void BuildTable(string sortFilterMethod, string sortFilterType, 
    string sortFilterValue)
{
    Type t = typeof(Eng); //just an example, will eventually be selected programatically
    using (TestEngContext context = new TestEngContext())
    {
        context.Set<t>().Where() //etc.;
    }
}
```

I get the error message "t is variable used like a type" when I try and set the `DbSet` type to `t`.

Is there a way to explicitly state that `t` should be treated as a type, not a variable?

Thanks

Comment: When you say it will be selected programatically, what do you mean? Can't you make the `BuildTable` method generic? Why do you need this to be known at runtime?

Comment: I mean that the type of type ````t```` will be selected programatically, possibly by passing the type to the method when it is called, or by using a switch statement in the function (a poor solution, I know, but I can't think of anything else...). The trouble is, I have the exact same issue when I try to make the method generic - I can't pass the type I want to the method explicity, because I don't know what it is at compile time, so I just get the same error about trying to use a variable as a type when I call the function.

Comment: But how can you not know the type until runtime, that makes no sense to me.

Comment: I am trying to choose the type which I use based on a string contained in the url of the page - I want to be able to quickly extend the functionality of the page without having to write a lot of switch statement cases or similar. I want to be able to get the correct data type based on the url and put that straight into the linq query - so in that way, I don't really know what type I want to use until runtime. Sorry for being confusing, I myself am very confused by this problem.

Comment: I think what you want to do is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2493336 (not a list in your case but it's still the same idea). Not sure it's the best way to achieve what you want with EF but I don't know the framework enough to tell.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041821/dynamically-access-table-in-ef-core-2-0/48042166#48042166. Pay attention to the comments under the answer. While you can get access to a non generic `IQueryable` instance, there is almost nothing to be done with it because all LINQ methods are defined for generic `IQueryable<T> ` or `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: fair enough - I believe I have found a solution (it's not perfect but it works...) - make a generic method, and call it with a known type from a switch statement where the cases correspond to the url string I wanted to use to decide which type to use.