# Can I dynamically create a list of variable type?

Tags: c#

I have 4 `public` classes, with a bunch of properties each: `MoveUpdateEntry`, `FullServiceEntry`, `SeamlessAcceptanceEntry`, and `UndocumentedEntry`.

I have a dictionary containing excerpts of a given filename, along with a correlation in place to determine the string equivalent of the class's name I need to instantiate:

```cs
private static Dictionary<string, string> dEntryCorr = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"MU_MU", "MoveUpdateEntry" },
    {"FS_BQ", "FullServiceEntry" },
    {"FS_BF", "FullServiceEntry" },
    {"SE_NS", "SeamlessAcceptanceEntry" },
    {"SE_U_", "UndocumentedEntry" }
};
```

[I've tried using Reflections as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493215/create-list-of-variable-type), but simply trying to run the following gives me an error:

```cs
string fileToProcess = "MU_MU.json";
Type entryType = Type.GetType( dEntryCorr[ fileToProcess.Substring(0,5) ], true );
```

`System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'MoveUpdateEntry' from assembly 'DataLoaderJSON, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.'`

My end goal here is to be able to dynamically pick a type to make a `List<>` of, based on the filename. (e.g. `MU_MU.json` will create `List<MoveUpdateEntry>`, `FS_BQ.json` creates `List<FullServiceEntry>`, etc.)

Is this possible in C#?

TLDR:
I want to create a List<> with a class type that is determined by a string. This is a matter of abstraction.

Comment: Are you asking how to create create an instance of a generic type at run time or are you asking how to load dlls? They are different questions.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm asking how I create a list of a custom class by its string name, or at the very least instantiate an instance of that very class

Comment: `string typeName = "Namespace." + dEntryCorr[fileToProcess.Substring(0, 5)] + ", Assembly";`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11107562/8967612).

Comment: Just when serializing, use `typeof(MoveUpdateEntry).AssemblyQualifiedName`

Comment: While it is possible to instantiate a type-specific `List<T>` and assign it to a `dynamic` or `object` variable, I'm not sure that will help you meet your goals-- at compile time, your code will have no idea what type the list is so you won't be able to do anything useful with it. You may as well just use a `List<object>` or a `List<dynamic>`.

Comment: What John said, and also a question.  Is your requirement a) simply that you use the filename to select the generic type?  Or b) must the string type name be used in the process?  ("TLDR: I want to create a List<> with a class type that is determined by a string." --> the class name string or the filename string?)  If you have a reference to this assembly and all of these type definitions, why not just switch on the file name substring, and in each case instantiate the list with the appropriate type parameter?

Comment: The question you linked to in the question is indeed answer to your question (I've added one more duplicate that shows essentially the same code as you already have. There is nothing wrong with code in the question and that code already answers your own question. Obviously you need to pass correct arguments to the code but without [MCVE] it is not possible to advice on what correct code should be (presumably you already checked what `GetType` expects as parameters and confirmed that they are correct)

Answer (score 1):

One way to get a `Type` from a `string`:

```
        string fileToProcess = "MU_MU.json";
        var entryType = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
            .GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == dEntryCorr[fileToProcess.Substring(0, 5)]);
```

(If there are more than one `Type` with the name `entryType` will only contain one of them.)