# Create populated List<> from runtime Type C#

Tags: c#

I have an `object` that I know is a list, but I do not know the `Type` until runtime. It could be a reference type or a value type. I'm trying to avoid using `dynamic` if possible to follow coding standards. I have something that works right now, but it feels sloppy and uses `dynamic`.

```
    private static List<Change> MyMethod(this object source, object target)
    {
            Type type = source.GetType();
            Type itemType;
            if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
            {
                itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                if (itemType.IsPrimitive || itemType == typeof(string))
                {
                    dynamic sourceList;
                    dynamic targetList;

                    if (itemType == typeof(string))
                    {
                        sourceList = (List<string>)source;
                        targetList = (List<string>)target;
                    }
                    else if (itemType == typeof(int))
                    {
                        sourceList = (List<int>)source;
                        targetList = (List<int>)target;
                    }
                    else if (itemType == typeof(long))
                    {
                        sourceList = (List<long>)source;
                        targetList = (List<long>)target;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sourceList = (List<object>)source;
                        targetList = (List<object>)target;
                    }

                    // get sourceList.Count etc
            }

    }
```

Does anyone know a better way I could do this?

Comment: Note that you can't cast a list of any arbitrary type (e.g. a `List<string>`) to a `List<object>`.  It will fail at run-time. What are you going to _do_ with the list that you can't just use a non-generic interface like `IList` or `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2493336/8967612)?

Comment: Once you've got your lists, what do you expect to do with them? Ie, what calls will you make in the `get sourceList.Count etc` part exactly, apart from count?

Comment: @Alejandro I check the count to see if they have the same number of elements, and do a !new HashSet<dynamic>(sourceList).SetEquals(targetList) if they do have the same number of elements to see if those elements are the same.

Comment: This is exactly an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Your real problem is comparing two lists, not creating a list from an unknown type. From your comment, your problem is exactly solved by calling `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`.

Comment: @Alejandro I don't think I was explicit enough, I need to determine the number of elements that are different. i.e. sourceList has 5 elements, targetList has 4 I should return "1 element was removed from the list".

Answer (score 0):

If you "expect" a specific type and the object "source" is actually an object[], you can do something like this:

```
public static List<T> ObjectArrToList<T>(this object source)
{
    Type t = source.GetType();

    if (t.IsArray)
    {
        Array arr = (Array)source;
        return arr.Cast<T>().ToList();
    }

    return new List<T>();
}

//Example use: (int is expected)
List<int> x = v.ObjectArrToList<int>();
```